# Mikrotik multiple ip on one VAN (routeOS 7)

Tags: ip, wan

[image]
There is a main ip address external 88.200.132.250

There are additional IPs on the same interface:
88.200.132.251

88.200.132.252

88.200.132.253

88.200.132.254
I access the Internet through the main ip and I have a port forwarded to the outside. I can access my server using an external ip from anywhere in the world.

Now I have a second server that I want to hang it on an additional ip.

This does not work. With the update to the latest version of the OS, this has probably changed.
When adding an additional address, a route is automatically added that cannot be deleted.

google search mikrotik